# Роззувати. Розбувати. Визувати

Tags: різниця-між-словами, діалектизми, розмовна-українська

Наштовхнувся у перекладі книги Звонко Карановича "Три картини перемоги" на таке речення: `Драгсі подивився на нього байдужим поглядом, визувся й ліг.`

І виявив у [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/) наступне:

[Роззувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/rozzuvaty) - Скидати взуття з чиїх-небудь ніг.

[Розбувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/rozbuvaty) - те ж саме, тільки розмовне.

[Визувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/vyzuvaty) - те ж саме, тільки діалектичне.

Скажіть, будь ласка, в якому саме діалекті використовується `визувати`? З цитат бачу, що є у Франка. Чи значить це, що діалектизм галицький?

`Розбувати` чув навіть у Донецькій області, то ж припускаю, що це розмовне по всій території України. Чи це дійсно так?

Comment: найкраще було б, якщо б відповів хтось із західних областей (з підтвердженням/спростуванням тез про галицизм "визуватися" і загальноукраїнськість "розбуватися")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Розбуватися* чула на Полтавщині (нехай це буде на підтримку всеукраїнськості слова).
А якщо шукати в інтернетах *визуватися*, то вискакують в результатах тернопільський [форум](http://forum.te.ua/showthread.php?t=80854&highlight=%E2%E5%F1%B3%EB%FC%ED%E5%20%EF%EB%E0%F2%F2%FF&page=57), коментарі на довколальвівських сайтах-[/1/](http://tuning.lviv.ua/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=47381#post_content1329282)-[/2/](http://posydenky.lvivport.com/threads/vidpochinok-na-lvivschini.42342/page-5), трускавецькі [новини](http://djerela.com.ua/news/truskavets/kurortniy-park-truskavtsya-vchergove-zatopilo), кілька різного-[/3/](https://ask.fm/id137193879)-[/4/](http://maysterni.com/publication.php?id=81396&comment_id=627146397#627146397)-[/5/](https://zbruc.eu/node/47425) й [оповідання](http://coollib.net/b/297100/read) Галини Пагутяк (нехай це буде на підтримку західності слова).

Comment: а ви зможете додати до своєї відповіді посилання-приклади (навіть якщо це посилання на результати пошуку)?

Comment: додала, що бачила